# Clickable images in widget. KIVY. PYTHON

Tags: python, image, widget, kivy

```
Can some please help me start a code that displays more than one image horizontally
or vertically. These images should be to display other pages when clicked.
```

I have tried writing different types of codes but they never execute they program as intended.

ex:

```
<MainPage>:
    Image:
    size: (1, None)
    #pos_hint:
    source: 'desktop/advisory.png'
    on_press: open.adivsorypage()
```

If anyone can give me a visual example or sample for me to study, I would love that. Thanks!

**EDIT:

```
import kivy
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.app import App

class InterfaceManager(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(InterfaceManager, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.first = Button(text="First")
        self.first.bind(on_press=self.show_second)

        self.second = Image(source="parentaladvisory.jpg")
        self.second.bind(on_press=self.show_final)

        self.final = Label(text="Hello World")
        self.add_widget(self.first)

        #I wanted to make the "final" display two of more images.

    def show_second(self, button):
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.add_widget(self.second)

    def show_final(self, button):
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.add_widget(self.final)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return InterfaceManager(orientation='vertical')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Code2:

```
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<MainPage>:
    size_hint: .5, .5
    auto_dismiss: False
    title: 'Hello world'
    HelpMe_Image:
        source: 'helpme.png'
        on_press: root.dismiss()
    Games_Image:
        source: 'games.png'
        on_press: root.dismiss()

''')

class MainPage(App):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):

        b = Button(source='desktop/intrologo2.png', on_press=self.show_mainpage)

        return b

    def show_mainpage(self, b):
        p = MainPage()
        p.open()

TestApp().run()
```

Comment: How about posting a full minimal working example of what you're trying, or where you've been able to get to? Your code snippet doesn't really do anything so it's not much to base an answer on.

Comment: @inclement Here is an examples. Honestly I have more 8 different codes. If i could post all, I would.

Comment: In code 2, `MainPage` extends `App` when you probably meant to extend `Popup`. In both, you're binding to an `on_press` event which `Image` does not have. Try using `ButtonBehavior` to make a clickable `Image` like in [this example](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.html).